# Convert Algo to C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array

```
MAXIMA(int n, Point P[1 . . . n])
1 for i <-- 1 to n 
2 do maximal <-- true
3 for j <-- 1 to n 
4 do
5 if (i != j)&(P[i].x <= P[j].x)&(P[i].y <= P[j].y) 
6 then maximal <-- false break
7 if maximal
8 then output P[i].x, P[i].y
```

This is algorithm : basically they gave me points `{12, 12},{14, 10},{15, 7},{7, 7},{11, 5},{13, 3},{5, 1},{7, 13},{4,11},{9,10},{2,5},{4,4}`
That the out put will be relate to Row , COL OR X , Y so Maximum of X&Y will be result or can say the point which is not dominated by others in mean of x or y so my code is:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<conio.h>
    using namespace std;

    struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;

};

int main()
    {
      Point P[12][2] = {  {12, 12},{14, 10},{15, 7},{7, 7},{11, 5},{13, 3}{5,1},{7, 13},{4,11},{9,10},{2,5},{4,4}    };


      bool maxim=true;
      for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) 
          do {
            if(i != j && P[i].x <= P[j].x && P[i].y <= P[j].y)  {
              cout << array[i][j] <<"\t" ;
              cout<<"\n";
              maxim=false;

            }
          } while(maxim=true);
          break;
        }
      }
      _getch();
      return 0;
    }
```

My output is not same as it should be Output Should be:

```
(7 13) (12 12) (14 10) (15 7)
```

As you can see in the first point no one dominates 13

2nd (12 , 12)

3rd (14, 10)

4th (15,7)

Comment: `array[i]` is a `int *`, not an int, since `array` is a 2d-array. So `array[i]<=array[j+1]` will compare two pointers. It will not magically know, that you want to interpret 2 ints as point and compare the points.

Comment: How i can do bro can you write this code with fix error

Comment: Thank you sir for writing it in good programing practice ..

Comment: Are you aware that `break` bails out of `do`/`while`? From the Algo, I would believe it should bail out of the `for` loop (around `do`/`while`). And then, `while(maxim=true)` (-> assignment!) Better: `while (maxim)`.

Comment: Have a look at the Algo again: `maximal` is assigned _in_ the most outer loop but you do it _out_ side.

Comment: Ohhh! thank you sir i will change now but output is still not what is should be..

Comment: Then sir again do is written inside so how can have 2 do loops and only closed one

Comment: The advice of the answer to resemble the Algo closer (by using a `struct { int x, y; }` instead of an array in array), appears very reasonable to me. (By this, you wouldn't have had the issue with the `break`.)

Comment: I never used struct before if you can help me with it i will be very thankful

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your Algo. I believe the missing indentation was essential. By indentation the loop bodies were denoted. As it is now, it's hard to understand what is inside the loops and what outside.

Comment: Sir can you make this give output as asked for ignoring ALgo

Comment: The answer provides exactly the snippets what are needed. [struct (C programming language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)). (It's not about C++ but C but for your purpose it may be sufficient to get started.)

Comment: Sir i have did some changes added structure but now its giving an error

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between the two pieces of code, is that the first one has a point class and second has not.

You can simply write one yourself.

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;   
}
```

(Yes, that's a struct, not a class, but let's keep it as simple as possible)

Then you can use an array to store the points, as you did before:

```
Point array[] = { {12, 12},{14, 10},{15, 7},{7, 7},{11, 5},{13, 3},{5, 1},{7, 13},{4,11},{9,10},{2,5},{4,4} };
```

Then you can use almost the same loop as in the original:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
    {
        if(i != j && P[i].x <= P[j].x && P[i].y <= P[j].y) 
        {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to work out the details for yourself, but I hope it points you in the right direction.